# CFThread batch proccess - Records being processed multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, coldfusion

We are sending out a large number of emails via a batch process. This process runs inside CFThread. Each recordset is retrieved from SQL Server. When we loop through the emails, we update the records as sent.

When we run the process every minute, it works fine. When running it every 30 seconds, it starts processing records multiple times.

Although we flag records as "pulled", were are still facing issues.
It looks like while the 1st request is still processing, the 2nd request starts. The 2nd request retrieves records before the 1st request can flag them as "pulled". So the same records are processed twice.

I don't want to lock the table because while I'm pulling records, I'm also sending emails and updating other records as sent in same table.

Database: (**pseudocode**)

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @MyTempTable table(
ID INT  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
emailBody varchar(max),
eMailfromdisplay varchar(200),
eMailFromAdr varchar(200),
eMailsubject varchar(200),
emailAdr varchar(200),
FirstName_vch varchar(250),
LastName_vch varchar(250),
Sent INT,
pulled INT,
masterEmailTableID BIGINT
);


insert into @MyTempTable
select Distinct top 1000
    emailBody,
    eMailfromdisplay,
    eMailFromAdr,
    eMailsubject,
    emailAdr,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Sent,
    pulled ,
    masterEmailTableID
from 
    emailMasteTable 

where 
    pulled  = 0 and
    Sent    = 0



SELECT TOP 1000 id
    ,masterEmailTableID
    ,Email_adr
    ,firstName
    ,LastName
    ,Sent
    ,pulled
 FROM @MyTempTable where sent = 0 and pulled = 0    



  -- Other tables status updates 

update emailMasteTable set pulled = 1 where EmailID IN (Select distinct masterEmailTableID from @MyTempTable);

END
```

ColdFusion : (**pseudocode**)

```
<cfquery  name="getMessages">
    exec spGetEmailMessages
</cfquery>


<cfoutput query="getMessages">

    <cfmail>
    <!--- Email Stuff --->


        <cfquery>
            update emailMasteTable set sent = 1 where EmailID = #getMessages.masterEmailTableID#;
        </cfquery>
    </cfmail>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I think It's not possible to say without seeing the actual script can you please share if it is possible.

Comment: If multiple threads can potentially access the records , it is not enough to flag them as completed *after* they are processed. You MUST implement some sort of locking mechanism to prevent race conditions. For example, you could implement multiple statuses: new, processing, completed, failed. Check for records with status new and flag them *when they are retrieved*. That prevents some other process from pulling the same data. When processing is complete, mark them as completed/failed as usual.

Comment: *although we flag records when we pull as pulled but still facing issues* That would not happen if done correctly. You need to post some code. Specifically that part of the logic.

Comment: Are you really looking to send 1 million emails every 30 seconds, plus do database updates as well?

Comment: Not @ all every 30 seconds 1000 emails, I'll update code sample also..

Comment: Just Added (**pseudo code**)  i can't copy/paste  actual code.  hope it will help to understand my issue.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading up on [how locking works in SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx#Lock_Engine). It is a big topic, but in a nutshell, simply wrapping the statements in a stored procedure does not mean access is somehow single threaded or that other threads are magically prevented from grabbing the same set of records. Nothing in the current code prevents the same batch of records from being "*read*" multiple times before the UPDATE kicks in. In fact the more threads involved, and frequent the interval, the more likely it is that multiple threads WILL process the same records.

It is not enough to flag a batch of records as "in use" *after* they are retrieved. They must be flagged *when* they are retrieved. For example, run the UPDATE to flag a batch of records. Use an [OUTPUT clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to capture the ids and store them in some sort of temp table. Then JOIN back to the temp table to perform any additional operations. Given that it is a frequently accessed table you should do some profiling to determine the optimal/most efficient approach.

```
-- Stores next batch of ids
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ( masterEmailTableID BIGINT );

-- Flag next batch as being "processed"
-- Note: Without an order by clause result order is arbitrary
UPDATE TOP (1000) BigTable
SET    Pulled = 1
OUTPUT inserted.masterEmailTableID INTO @TempTable
WHERE  Pulled = 0
AND    Sent = 0

-- do other queries .... 

-- Return details for current batch
SELECT  main.masterEmailTableID
        , main.masterEmailTableID
        , ... other columns 
FROM    BigTable main INNER JOIN @TempTable tmp ON tmp.masterEmailTableID = main.masterEmailTableID
GO
```

Side note, you might also consider adding a unique batch number to your table to facilitate bulk status updates, rather than updating items individually.

Comment: Thank you! @Leigh  what you suggested it is not 100% of my solution but it gave me good direction,  what to do ... you are great :)...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what else did you need to do? Locking and grabbing the updated id's simultaneously should be all you need for batch processing.

Comment: Hi @Leigh, sorry for delay. Im selecting records -> updating first ->  fetching updated records only. so far working good.

Comment: i have question, now im using your given SQL, because it was duplicating now its less but still can you help me out..?.  `SET NOCOUNT ON BEGIN TRANSACTION engage_thread &  WITH (ROWLOCK)`  this is only change i did

Comment: Not sure I follow the issue.  Why would you need ROWLOCK with the code above?

Comment: because i have to secure my records, what im reading currently, while im reading and updating record other thread kicked then it will take some records what i have in my update queue. this is what is happening.

Comment: Are you *really* using the code above? Because it sounds like you are still using your original code. I do not see how what you described could even happen with the new code (not to mention what you are using a ROWLOCK for ...).  The UPDATE takes an exclusive lock which prevents any other threads from grabbing the same records. It also updates the "pulled" flag so the id's inserted into the table variable *cannot* be grabbed multiple times...

Comment: You did not answer my question :) Are you really using the *exact* code above? Can you post your current code?

Comment: im using your given example code of course it is not same im using some filtering function also to search end replace not main code is same.  `UPDATE TOP (500) WITH (ROWLOCK) ->   SET    Pulled = 1 -> storing in @variable OUTPUT `